# Why do the Node.js mongodb driver methods not invoke callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In the example below, I expect to see two lines from the `console.log` statements in the terminal but I only get one since the second callback is never fired. I'm using mongodb (2.4.8_1) and Node.js (0.10.22) from MacPorts with the official Node.js mongodb driver (1.3.20) from NPM (1.3.15). How can this happen?

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function (err, db) {
    var query = { _id: new mongodb.ObjectID };

    console.log('connect!');

    db.collection('test').findOne(query, function (err, doc) {

        console.log('findOne!');

    });
});
```

Comment: Works fine when I try your code.

Comment: I think it's a bug. See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-92 Rolling back the driver to 1.3.19 solved the problem for me.

Comment: @BrandonZacharie that bug was fixed [here](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/commit/21522fa792b8cd127b53ee65f779e62e3091f685#diff-6a70d87818521819afccdee24154801e), and the `1.3.20` in the NPM repo should be working (it does for me). You probably installed it at a time when it was still broken.

Comment: That sounds about right. I'm guessing someone pushed the fixed build to NPM without bumping the version number to `1.3.21` which screwed anyone with a cached copy of the broken one.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you run `new mongodb.ObjectID` it creates a new ID value - which you then instantly search for without inserting a document with. So how can it find a document, and hence show the second log line?

Comment: In this example I expected there to be no result. The callback is supposed to be invoked anyway but with `doc` set to `null`.